# SharePoint MOSS 2007 - Calculated field - IsBlank function

Tags: sharepoint, expression, sharepoint-2007

I'm sure that this could be a simple question but I am using SharePoint 2007 and trying to create a calculated column to check if weather or not a field is empty. What I am trying to accomplish is get a formula that will check if the column is empty and if it is then return "This is empty" or else return "This is not empty".

So far I got this formula below but I really dont understand how to get the else statement in here. Not having much luck finding the info on Microsoft's site.

```
=IF(Isblank([Column1]),"This is empty")
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for the IF function

IF takes two parameters and you are using only the first, the second parameter is the else...

```
IF( Isblank([Column1]) , "This is empty" , "This is NOT empty" )
```

In other words.. RTFM

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx